# How to open numeric keypad for html password field in IOS/ANDROID

Tags: javascript, html, ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to open numeric keyboard for android/ios hybrid app. I have tried below code but it isn't working -

```
   <input type="password"
   pattern="[0-9]*"
   inputMode="numeric" />
```